# what is the validity of a german conference visa

Tags: ugandan-citizens

I intend to travel to Germany for a conference in June this year, can I apply
for my via now. Shall this visa still be valid by the time I intend to travel

Answer (score 2):

You will need an uniform short-stay Schengen visa.

The earliest time you can apply for such a visa is **three months before** the start of your intended visit. ([Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32009R0810), article 9).

So you will have to wait a bit yet. *Within* that time limit, though, it is recommended to apply as early as possible.